# Multiple dependent dropdown component in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to create a widget in flutter that will dynamically render dropdowns and their options and return them in a json format. If you have certain data passed to you from an API like

```
data:{
"value1":["option1','option2'],
"value2":{
"subvalue1":['option1','option2'],
"subvalue2":['option3','option4'],
},
"value3":{
"subvalue1":{
"anothersubvalue1":['option1','option2'],
"anothersubvalue2":['option1','option2'],
},
"subvalue2":{
"anothersubvalue1":['option4','option5'],
"anothersubvalue2":['option5','option6'],
}
}
```

How can i achieve my goal here.
My goal is :
Creating a flutter widget(or logic for making this in any programming language) which on passing a value like this, should first render a dropdown which lets people select any key from the dropdown in this data variable. i.e. should be allowed to choose between value1,value2, value3, etc. and so on. Then for objects in that dictionary (Map) if they have list like option1 and 2 in the value 1 then another dropdown should appear with heading value 1 and the options to select from will be option1 and 2. But if they select value2 then dynamically another dropdown must be rendered with the heading value 2 and that will contain options to choose between subvalue1 and subvalue2 and when user chooses one from that the options of those corresponding values must be shown. Similarly for value3 which has two other subvalues and each sub value again has other dictionaries, it should display the dropdown in this order: first the dropdown where the user chooses between value1,2,3 and when 3 is choosen another dropdown is rendered to choose between subvalue1 and subvalue2 and when one is choosen from this another dropdown that lets you choose between anothersubvalue1 or 3 of that subvalue and when any one of the "anothersubvalue" is choosen then another dropdown must appear which will let you choose between options1 and 2 or options 4 and 5 and so on.
I want to make this dynamic and based on the data received from the api the flutter widget should be able to make dynamic nested dropdowns based on the data no matter how many nested objects are present and the widget should also return a json data containing which value is choosen for which dropdown.
How can i achieve this ?

The code i am using is :

```
class DynamicDropdowns extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;

  DynamicDropdowns({required this.data});

  @override
  _DynamicDropdownsState createState() => _DynamicDropdownsState();
}

class _DynamicDropdownsState extends State<DynamicDropdowns> {
  Map<String, dynamic> selectedValues = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedValues.keys.isEmpty ? null : selectedValues.keys.last,
          items: widget.data.keys.map((value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValues.removeWhere(
                  (key, _) => widget.data[key] is Map || key == newValue);
              selectedValues[newValue] = null;
            });
          },
        ),
        if (selectedValues.isNotEmpty)
          DynamicDropdowns(
            data: widget.data[selectedValues.keys.last],
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> getSelectedValues() {
    Map<String, dynamic> result = {};
    for (var key in selectedValues.keys) {
      if (widget.data[key] is Map) {
        final subResult = DynamicDropdowns(
          data: widget.data[key],
        ).getSelectedValues();
        if (subResult.isNotEmpty) {
          result[key] = subResult;
        }
      } else {
        result[key] = selectedValues[key];
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}

t
```

his is what i have tried and it is not working.
i want a universally usable component that can be used to render the dropdowns dynamically such that every dropdown will be handled by this widget and we can simply pass the json data and get the json data of selected values as output from the widget.

Answer (score 1):

To create a dynamic nested dropdown widget in Flutter that can handle arbitrary levels of nested data and return the selected values as JSON output, you can use a recursive approach. Here's an updated version of your widget that achieves this functionality:

```
class DynamicDropdowns extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data;
  final Function(Map<String, dynamic>) onValueChanged;

  DynamicDropdowns({
    required this.data,
    required this.onValueChanged,
  });

  @override
  _DynamicDropdownsState createState() => _DynamicDropdownsState();
}

class _DynamicDropdownsState extends State<DynamicDropdowns> {
  Map<String, dynamic> selectedValues = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.onValueChanged(selectedValues);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: selectedValues.keys.isEmpty ? null : selectedValues.keys.last,
          items: widget.data.keys.map((value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValues.removeWhere(
                  (key, _) => widget.data[key] is Map || key == newValue);
              selectedValues[newValue] = null;
              widget.onValueChanged(selectedValues);
            });
          },
        ),
        if (selectedValues.isNotEmpty)
          DynamicDropdowns(
            data: widget.data[selectedValues.keys.last],
            onValueChanged: (value) {
              selectedValues[selectedValues.keys.last] = value;
              widget.onValueChanged(selectedValues);
            },
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here's how you can use this widget:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dynamic Dropdowns Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: DynamicDropdownsDemo(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DynamicDropdownsDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DynamicDropdownsDemoState createState() => _DynamicDropdownsDemoState();
}

class _DynamicDropdownsDemoState extends State<DynamicDropdownsDemo> {
  Map<String, dynamic> selectedValues = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        DynamicDropdowns(
          data: {
            "value1": ["option1", "option2"],
            "value2": {
              "subvalue1": ["option1", "option2"],
              "subvalue2": ["option3", "option4"],
            },
            "value3": {
              "subvalue1": {
                "anothersubvalue1": ["option1", "option2"],
                "anothersubvalue2": ["option1", "option2"],
              },
              "subvalue2": {
                "anothersubvalue1": ["option4", "option5"],
                "anothersubvalue2": ["option5", "option6"],
              }
            }
          },
          onValueChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedValues = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 20),
        Text(
          "Selected Values: ${selectedValues.toString()}",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, the DynamicDropdowns widget recursively creates nested dropdowns based on the provided data. The onValueChanged callback is called whenever a dropdown value changes, allowing you to capture the selected values and use them as needed.

Comment: It seems to work as well as the nicest one. Great job!

Comment: in this code wont we get error in the line selectedValuse[newValue]=null as the argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type string?
when i tried this code and tried to remove this error there were issues in rendering the dropdowns